# Can someone explain how this method works for finding $y_p$ for $y''-2y'+y=2e^x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Can someone explain how this method works for finding $y_p$ for
> $y''-2y'+y=2e^x$?

**page 1 of answer:**
[image]

**page 2 of answer:**
[image]

The thing i don't understand is how $$(1/f(d))*x=(1/f(d))*e^x$$
and so on. Where does $x$ come from how they are equal to each other?

and why are we driving $f(a)$ under and multiplying the expression by $x$?
I would be thankful if someone could explain the part b, where we try to find $y_p.$

Comment: this is not a good method. Use the standard undetermined coefficients method. Much easier to understand.

Comment: Here $D$ is the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.  Before this point in your course you should have done calculations with $D$ and such combinations as $f(D)$.  Without that backtround, these two pages are, indeed, impenetrable.  But I disagree with @Nasser ... this is a nice method once you understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula is called  [Exponential response formula](http://Exponential%20response%20formula) 
And you made a mistake in the formula it should be for $f(a) \ne 0$:
$$\dfrac 1 {f(D)}e^{ax}=\dfrac {e^{ax}}{f(a)}$$
For $f(a)=0$ the formula becomes:
$$\dfrac 1 {f(D)}e^{ax}=\dfrac {xe^{ax}}{f'(a)}$$
Provided that $f'(a) \ne0$. This is called the **resonant response formula**.
Note that your differential equation is just:
$$(ye^{-x})''=2$$
Integrate twice.
$$y(x)=e^{x}(c_1x+c_2+x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Your method**

We were given a linear ordinary differential equation in the following form:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}{k_{i}\frac{d^{i}y}{dx^{i}}}=Ce^{sx}
$$

Notice that if we substitute $y=Be^{sx}$ into the equation and then solve for $B$ we will get the following:

$$
\begin{align}
B\sum_{i=0}^{n}{k_{i}\cdot s^{i}e^{sx}}&=Ce^{sx}\\
\\
B&=\frac{C}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{k_{i}\cdot s^{i}}}
\end{align}
$$

If $e^{sx}$ is not a homogenous solution of the ODE then we have gotten the particular solution for the ODE. Otherwise, we obtain $B=\frac{C}{0}$ which obviously is not correct. In this case substitute $y=Bxe^{sx}$ instead then solve for $B$. If we still get $B=\frac{C}{0}$, substitute $y=Bx^{2}e^{sx}$ instead, and so on.

This method is correct and will give you the particular solution. However it does not provide any insights on why the particular solution is in the form of $y_{p}=Bx^{m}e^{sx}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the case $f(a)\ne 0$ with $f(r)=0$, $f'(r)\ne 0$, you can "borrow" a part of the homogeneous solution to get
$$
f(D)^{-1}e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}-e^{rx}}{f(a)-f(r)}
$$
(Note that the expression on the left side is more symbolic or formal than exact, it is unique only up to addition of homogeneous solution terms.)

Then it is clearly visible that for $a\to r$ this converges to the derivative quotient
$$
\frac{xe^{rx}{f'(r)}.
$$
of the extended mean-value formula.

If $r$ is a double root, $f(r)=f'(r)=0$, $f''(r)\ne 0$, one can "borrow" complementary terms from the $e^{rx}$ and $xe^{rx}$ basis solutions to get
$$
f(D)^{-1}e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}-e^{rx}-(a-r)xe^{rx}}{f(a)-f(r)-(a-r)f'(r)}
$$
This reduces by twice applying the extended mean value theorem in the limit of $a\to r$ to
$$
\frac{x^2e^{rx}}{f''(r)},
$$
as claimed.